# Dont understand (Pipes) usage unix

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

I am studying for 'operational Systems' exams at my uni and i am having hard time understanding pipes usage (|).
 Here is an example i found on internet:

> ps -ax | grep Finder
>    Use the ps command to get a list of processes running on the system, and pass the list to grep to search for lines containing "Finder". (Usually, it'll find two: the Finder, and the processes executing grep Finder.)

What if i first write `ps -ax` and at next line `grep finder` ? wont it have the same result? why i have to pipe them together?

ps: Bigginer at unix shell commands and how it works.

Comment: *"What if i first write ps -ax and at next line grep finder ? wont it have the same result?"* Why don't you try it?

Comment: i run putty on my pc to have a unix like enviroment, at the moment i cant connect to it , sometimes does it. when i can i will try it mate

Comment: Cool cool. You could also run Linux in a VM like VirtualBox - it's pretty handy if you're forced to use Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about redirecting input and output.

If you were to type `ps -ax > processes`, you would create the file `processes` with a list of all the processes. This is redirecting output. All the data shown to the screen is instead written to a file.

If you were to type `grep Finder < processes`, you would search the file `processes` for the word Finder. This is redirecting input.

Pipe does both. It redirects the output of the command on the left side and redirects the input of the command on the right side.

```
$ ps -ax | grep Finder
```

is like

```
$ ps -ax > temp
$ grep Finder < temp
```

except all on one line with no temp file to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Unix is a file based system. And unless you specify where you want to redirect the output, it will be displayed on screen.

So if you type `ps ax`, it will list all the running processes **on the screen**.
So if you type `ps ax` first and then `grep` then you will get all the process and then you will get error as `grep` expects at least 2 parameters, `keyword` and `filename`.

So you have to do 2 steps.

```
 ps ax > filename
 grep finder filename
```

This will give you the result.

Pipe `|` redirects the output from left side, as a file, to the right side command. So you can merge the 2 steps.

So instead of all above, you can just say, `ps ax|grep finder` , which will pass the output of `ps ax` as a file to `grep` command.

Note than in this way, you didn't specify a file name to `grep` directly. Instead you are telling it to use the output of `ps ax` as a file

Answer (score 1):

No, the result would not be the same in the two cases you mentioned above. Try it out.

`ps -ax` by itself would send its result to the standard output.
`grep Finder` by itself would not work at all

[pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) creates a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication. So, `ps -ax | grep finder`, essentially redirects the output of `ps -ax` as an input stream into the `grep Finder` command, which in turn searches for the string 'Finder' in that stream.